# How to style a shortcode based on acf

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shortcode

I want to combine the output of an acf field from my page with my shortcode. The text should be underlined with the color set via an acf field.

I tried to call the field color and set the text-decoration via an inline style. But this is not working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
function quote_func($atts, $content = null){
 $color = get_field('color');
    $output = '<div>';
    $output .= '<span style="text-decoration-color:' . echo the_field('color'); . '">' . $content . '</span>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'quote', 'quote_func' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should echo the variable you set in the beginning of your function.

```
function quote_func($atts, $content = null){
   $color = get_field('color');
   $output = '<div>';
   $output .= '<span style="text-decoration-color:' . $color . '">' . $content . '</span>';
   $output .= '</div>';

   return $output;
} 
add_shortcode( 'quote', 'quote_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

get_field('color') isn't enough to get the value if you're not inside a post, you need a second parameter. You are in a shortcode then you need to use:

`get_field('color', $postId);`

To get the id of the post from within shortcode you can use:

```
global $post;
$postId = $post->ID;
```

If you use the same color for each post you may have the option page and in that case you need to use:

```
get_field('color', 'option');
```